# How to disable screen saver in WinRT

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

This is how you do it on Windows Phone 7 http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-lock-and-run.html is it possible in Windows 8?

Comment: Perhaps it is my assumption that needs to be questioned. In Windows 8, are applications suspended when the lock screen appears?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't work for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample is showing you how to implement the functionality so your app will still "run" when the device is locked. It only seems to work with a kind of "background tasks" which makes it not exactly the same as it is for Windows Phone.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Lock-screen-apps-sample-9843dc3a

Please note that an app that can run when the device is locked should have at least one of the following background tasks:

- Control Channel
- Timer
- Push Notification

Here is some more info on the lockscreen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh779720

**UPDATE:**

As far as I have found there is no exact behaviour like in Windows phone to run your app under the lockscreen. There are a few recent posts on the MSDN blogs which explain the background model http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Sorry to see that at this moment there is no way to make it work under the lockscreen

Comment: No, I am sorry, this is not the same thing. The sample you suggest here is showing how to add your app to the lock screen so it has background priority to run every 15 minutes and in 2 CPU seconds. What I am asking is to continue running why the lock screen is visible.

Comment: Hi Jerry!  Check out http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411

Comment: @JP that's a background task. You know the running app on the phone that runs even during screen off? That is what I was asking. It's my terribly worded question. Sorry.